# Name with title a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a name to my pandas df but I am failing. I want the two columns to be named "Job department" and "Amount"

```
df["sales"].value_counts()
>>>>>>output
sales          4140
technical      2720
support        2229
IT             1227
product_mng     902
marketing       858
RandD           787
accounting      767
hr              739
management      630
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

Then I do:

```
job_frequency = pd.DataFrame(df["sales"].value_counts(), columns=['Job department','Amount'])
print(job_frequency)
```

**but**  I get:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Job department, Amount]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for index name with 
[`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
job_frequency = (df["sales"].value_counts()
                            .rename_axis('Job department')
                            .reset_index(name='Amount'))
```

---

```
print(job_frequency)
  Job department  Amount
0          sales    4140
1      technical    2720
2        support    2229
3             IT    1227
4    product_mng     902
5      marketing     858
6          RandD     787
7     accounting     767
8             hr     739
9     management     630
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
job_frequency = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'Job department': df["sales"].value_counts().index,
        'Amount': df["sales"].value_counts().values
    }
)
```